# PyFMI different results between model exchange and co-simulation?

Tags: python, modelica, openmodelica, fmi, pyfmi

When simulating the cartpole problem as an FMU in PyFMI I get different results giving the same input depending on if I use "model exchange" or "co-simulation". The ME results are correct, the CS results seem completely off.

**Model exchange results**

[image: model exchange results]

```
model = load_fmu(fmu='CartPole.fmu', 
                 kind='ME')

model.set('theta_0', 0)
model.set('m_cart', 20)
model.set('m_pole', 5)
model.set('length', 2)
model.set('poleCartConnection.density', 0)
model.set('f', 0)
res = model.simulate(start_time=0, final_time=10)


plt.plot(res['f'])
plt.plot(res['x'])
plt.plot(res['x_dot'])
plt.plot(res['theta'])
plt.plot(res['theta_dot'])
plt.legend(['f', 'x', 'x_dot', 'theta', 'theta_dot'])
plt.show()
```

compared to (i.e. exactly the same but using CS instead of ME)

```
model = load_fmu(fmu='CartPole.fmu', 
                 kind='CS')

model.set('theta_0', 0)
model.set('m_cart', 20)
model.set('m_pole', 5)
model.set('length', 2)
model.set('poleCartConnection.density', 0)
model.set('f', 0)
res = model.simulate(start_time=0, final_time=10)


plt.plot(res['f'])
plt.plot(res['x'])
plt.plot(res['x_dot'])
plt.plot(res['theta'])
plt.plot(res['theta_dot'])
plt.legend(['f', 'x', 'x_dot', 'theta', 'theta_dot'])
plt.show()
```

**co-simulation results with default ncp**

[image: co-simulation results with default ncp]

I suspect its due to the solver settings, but these cannot be set in the CS case? When I set the 'ncp' to a very high number, the error gets reduced.
Many thanks in advance for your replies!

**co-simulation results with high ncp**

[image: co-simulation with high ncp]

Cheers

Comment: What ist the generating tool?
Which solver is included in the CS FMU?
Can you share the original model and the FMU?

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the error in OpenModelica as well and it is indeed due to the solver settings and chosen integration method - checking them now.

Comment: As [stated here](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/4273) Euler is currently the only solver supported when exporting FMU's in OpenModelica (haven't tested the nightly 1.16 build) which is probably just to simple of a method (i.e. first-order). When using dassl in OpenModelica, the results are fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenModelica,  Euler is currently the only supported solver when exporting co-simulation FMU's [as stated here](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/4273). Version 1.16 of OpenModelica should solve this issue.